# How is balancing of binary trees implemented?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm studying how to balance trees and I have some questions

- Is it possible to balance a normal binary tree? If yes, which algorithm should be used?
- Do I necessarily have to use a AVL or Red-black tree to obtain a balanced tree? How do these work?

I read something about rotations, weights but I'm kind of confused right now

Comment: `Is it possible to balance a normal binary tree`: In `O(n)` you can build a complete tree, and populate it with the elements in in-order traversal. Is this kind of an answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... AVL and red-black trees are "normal binary trees" that are balanced, and keep that balance (for some definition of "balanced"). I'm not a computer science teacher to come up with my own explanation of the algorithms, and I guess you aren't looking for a cut&paste from Wikipedia :-)

Now, for balancing binary trees: if the tree is a search tree (i.e. 'sorted', but 'balanced' doesn't really make all that much sense if it's not) you could always just recreate the tree. The simplest algorithm is to use an array with all the elements from the tree, in sorted order (easily obtained from an inorder traversal). Then build an algorithm around this general idea:

- take the middle element of the array as the root of the tree. This will create a tree node, and two arrays "left" and "right", which are meant to form the left and right subtrees
- Apply this same algorithm recursively to create a tree from the "left" array and one from the "right" array. These two trees become the children of the parent node.

You might have to be careful with the case when the array has an even number of elements: there is no obvious "middle element", and removing one of the two candidates will create arrays of different sizes. I'm too lazy to analyze this further to see if that could offset the whole balancing thing.

Of course, doing something like this every time you change the tree isn't such a great idea; you really want to use self-balancing trees like AVL for that. Doing it after creating the tree might not be all that useful either: you could just use the array itself and do binary searches on it, instead of making a tree. The array IS just another form of a binary tree...

EDIT: there is a reason why a lot of computer scientists have spent a lot of time developing data structures and algorithms that perform well in certain situations. Rolling your own version of a balanced binary tree is unlikely to beat these...

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to balance a normal binary tree? If yes, which
> algorithm should be used?

In `O(n)` you can **build a complete tree, and populate it** with the elements in [in-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Inorder_Traversal).

It cannot be done better, because A BST might in rare cases decay to a chain (linked list), where all nodes have one son as null. In this cases, accessing the element in the middle is `O(n)` itself.

> Do I necessarily have to use a AVL or Red-black tree to obtain a
> balanced tree?

There are other balanced trees such as [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree), and other data structures (not trees) such as [skip-lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). You might want to have a look at a list of known **[data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)**, especially the [trees section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Trees).

> How do these work?

I find the wikipedia articles both on [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and [Red-Black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) very informative. If you have something specific you don't understand there - you should ask.

Also: **Trying to implement** a balanced trees on your own (Implement a known tree, not inventing a new one - of course) - is great for educational purposes, and by doing so - you will definitely understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you balance an unbalanced tree?**
Yes, You can. You use the same balance function you created for your AVL Tree inside a PostOrderTraversal function.

**Should You Do it?**
No!!! You should recreate it! Balancing the tree will cost you unnecessarily.

**How do I recreate it?**
Use an InOrderTraversal function to put your nodes into an array. Then use a variable that will always go to the middle of the array and the left middle, right middle and add the nodes to the new Tree.

**Is it possible to balance a normal binary tree? If yes, which algorithm should be used?
Do I necessarily have to use a AVL or Red-black tree to obtain a balanced tree? How do these work?**
In general, Trees are either unbalanced or balanced. AVL, Red-Black, 2-3, e.t.c. are just trees with some properties and according to their properties they use some extra variables and functions. Those extra variables and function can also be used in the "normal" binary trees. In other words those functions and variables are not bounded to their respective type of tree. The nodes of a "normal" binary tree always had a balance! You just didn't use it because you didn't care if the "normal" binary tree was balanced or not. They also always had a height, depth, e.t.c. You just didn't care. In general, you will realize at one point that all are a trade-off between speed and memory. If you know what you are doing, more memory usage will make your program faster. Less memory usage means more calculations so you will have a slower program.